# how to vacuum (reduce file size) on duckdb

Tags: duckdb

I am testing duckdb database for analytics and I must say is very fast. The issue is the database file is growing and growing but I need to make it small to share it.

In sqlite I recall to use the VACUUM commadn, but here same command is doing nothing. Size is the same.

how to reduce file size for duckdb database?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for something similar...

Comment: No clue. I exported the complete SQL dump code and then create all database using a different filename.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that this option is not available yet. What I use is EXPORT database command , create a new clean data file and then IMPORT.

Documentation here
https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/export

Answer (score 1):

As of DuckDB version 0.10.0:

[VACUUM Statement](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/statements/vacuum)

> The VACUUM statement alone does nothing and is at present provided for
> PostgreSQL-compatibility. The VACUUM ANALYZE statement recomputes
> table statistics if they have become stale due to table updates or
> deletions.