# How to reset the size of db file storage in duckdb?

Tags: duckdb

I create persistent duckdb database storage and populate it with data in python. However, after I drop the table in db file, the storage size did not change. Is there any possible way to to reduce the size of db file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66500383/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, thank you very much. I have donr that way